# gluProject equivalent in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, matrix, webgl

I'm looking for an equivalent of gluProject in javascript for use with WebGL.  Does anyone know where an open-source implementation is or how to implement it in javascript?

I'm using the glMatrix javascript library from here:

https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix

but it lacks a project function.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: I've had a couple of requests for a project/un-project function at this point, so I'll look into adding it soon. (I'm the author of glMatrix)

Comment: @Toji, that would be great!  The rest of the library is awesome, so this would top it off nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Take a look at WebGLU https://github.com/OneGeek/WebGLU
I have not yet worked with it but it seems what you are looking for.

I also found another project: http://code.google.com/p/ofxjavascript/wiki/ofxGlu It doesn't look too promesing though...
I would also suggest using a "higher" level javascript 3D engine if you are just beginning to learn WebGL. I learned a lot from existing solutions only to finally come up with my own libs.

Comment: Thanks, I found the unproject version of the function which should be enough.